# LINQ results to new Dataset Row

Tags: linq, dataset, visual-studio-2013

I have created a Dataset in Visual Studio 2013 called ChangeLog with two tables: ChangeMaster and ChangeDetail. The two tables are joined by a relationship on a single int key, only ChangeDetail plays a role in my issue. This is a reporting dataset and never resides in a database on disk.

I am reporting Audit data, i.e. changes to a record. Some of you might recognize the ApexSQL data tables as my audit source. The query below works fine if I replace Entities.ChangeLog.ChangeDetailRow with my own class call changeDetail. But I cannot get it to work with the native dataset table ChangeDetailRow. The error occurs on the the field I have enclosed in in '???' and it says 'Entities.ChangeLog.ChangeDetailRow does not contain a contructor that takes 0 arguments'. The only argument is (DataRowBuilder rb).

I can create new rows in C# for ChangeDetail using:

```
(Entities.ChangeLog.ChangeDetailRow)_changeDS.Tables["ChangeDetail"].NewRow();
```

but can't figure out what LINQ wants. I tried creating an extension method for ChangeDetail that accepts multiple arguments but did not succeed with that either.

What do I need to put inside the ???...???

```
List<Entities.ChangeLog.ChangeDetailRow> details =
    (from data in infoEntities.AUDIT_LOG_DATA
    join trx in infoEntities.AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTIONS on data.AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTION_ID equals trx.AUDIT_LOG_TRANSACTION_ID
    where PKs.Contains(data.PRIMARY_KEY) 
    select new ???Entities.ChangeLog.ChangeDetailRow???
    {
        PKInfoRequest = data.KEY1,
        Date = trx.MODIFIED_DATE,
        Action = trx.AUDIT_ACTION_ID,
        Field = data.COL_NAME,
        OldValue = data.OLD_VALUE_LONG,
        NewValue = data.NEW_VALUE_LONG
    }).ToList<Entities.ChangeLog.ChangeDetailRow>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering what says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowbuilder%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you probably can't create new row that way. Can you simply leave out part enclosed with '???' and try:

```
...
select new
    {
        PKInfoRequest = data.KEY1,
...
```

Then you can create rows with `.NewRow()` and fill them with data.

Comment: Yes, I can use var and the structure you are proposing. However, it means I still have the extra step of copying the var results into the ChangeDetail table, just as I do if I create my own class which mimics ChangeDetail. The reason for using ChangeDetail is that I am using DevExpress for reporting and it accepts Master-Detail relationships. The only way I know of defining that Master-Detail relation is in the Data Designer, hence I need to ultimately use the ChangeLog Dataset.

Comment: Can't help you any further. It seems it is not LINQ problem but DataRow problem. I only know basics and on MSDN it is suggested to take that extra step, so I would use it if it works. Optimize later :)

Comment: The link you provided pretty much sums up the situation. LINQ to Entities only works with zero parameter constructors and the ADO.NET data designer does not create such a constructor. It creates those, dare I say useless, Rowbuilder parameters which cannot be used.